# Benchmark on quick-bench.com is much faster with disabled optimizations

Tags: c++, optimization, microbenchmark, google-benchmark

I've created a very simple benchmark for illustration of *short string optimization* and run it on **quick-bench.com**. The benchmark works very well as for the comparison of SSO-disabled/enabled string class and the results are very consistent with both GCC and Clang. However, I realized that when I disable optimizations, the reported times are around 4 times faster than those observed with enabled optimizations (`-O2` or `-O3`), both with GCC and Clang.

The benchmark is here: http://quick-bench.com/DX2G2AdxUb7sGPE-zLRa41-MCk0.

Any idea what may cause the unoptimized benchmark to run 4-times faster?

Unfortunately, I can't see the generated assembly; don't know where the problem is (the "Record disassembly" box is checked but has no effect in my runs). Also, when I run the benchmark locally with Google Benchmark, the results are as expected, i.e., the optimized benchmark runs faster.

I also tried to compare both variants in Compiler Explorer and the unoptimized one seemingly executes much more instructions: https://godbolt.org/z/I4a171.

Comment: Have you read the notes under *More* -> *About Quickbench*? The values shown are not absolute times, but relative to a noop (which will likely also be influenced by optimization flags). It also says that the benchmarks are potentially run on different environments and not comparable.

Comment: @uneven_mark You're likely right. Yes, I've read the notes, just some time ago and I didn't remember that part about _noop potentially influenced by optimization flags_.

Comment: Well that part is my own conclusion, not what is actually written. I have not looked at the source code, but if it is implemented in the straight-forward way, then I would expect the flags to affect the noop time.

Comment: @uneven_mark There are several versions of NOOP there: https://github.com/FredTingaud/quick-bench-back-end/blob/master/app.js#L29. Just if you are interested. One would need to explore the generated assembly code to find out what NOOP is translated to, but I can't see it there. Even tried another browser, without success.

Comment: You can see [here](http://quick-bench.com/aiyAwMAoirMtqSSk0gf2M8Cx1ac). So you need to adjust your timings by a factor 6, roughly, which will make it less surprising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as discussed in the comments, the issue is that quick-bench.com does not show absolute time for the benchmarked code, but rather time relative to the time a no-op benchmark took. The no-op benchmark can be found in the source files of quick-bench.com:

```
static void Noop(benchmark::State& state) {
    for (auto _ : state) benchmark::DoNotOptimize(0);
}
```

All benchmarks of a run are compiled together. Therefore the optimization flags apply to it as well.

[Reproducing and comparing the no-op benchmark for different optimization levels](http://quick-bench.com/aiyAwMAoirMtqSSk0gf2M8Cx1ac) one can see, that there is about a 6 to 7 times speedup from the `-O0` to `-O1` version. When comparing benchmark runs done with different optimization flags, this factor in the baseline must be considered to compare results. The 4x speed-up observed in the question's benchmark is therefore more than compensated and the behavior is really as one would expect.

One main difference in compilation of the no-op between `-O0` and `-O1` is that for `-O0` there are some assertions and other additional branches in the google-benchmark code, that are optimized out for higher optimization levels.

Additionally at `-O0` each iteration of the loop will load into register, modify, and store to memory parts of `state` multiple time, e.g. for decrementing the loop counter and conditionals on the loop counter, while the `-O1` version will keep `state` in registers, making memory load/stores in the loop unnecessary. The former is much slower, taking at least a few cycles per iteration for necessary store-forwardings and/or reloads from memory.